# Schema Visualizer that includes views (for Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, schema

I was looking for something (preferably free) that would quickly visualise a schema in Oracle for me? I've found some that show the relationships between tables, but I haven't yet found one that includes views. I understand that views can be more complex than tables, but it would be good to have a visualiser that at least understands views which are simple joins etc. I'm happy to clean it up and add to it after, but just something that produces the basic relationships will be good.

Like I said, this is on an Oracle database, but if there is a database independent tool, I'm happy to dump out the sql that generates the schema and feed it to the tool.

Comment: I don't think you will find such a tool. The relationships between tables come from referential integrity constraints and views don't have such. While most tools read the views and their columns none go so far as to reverse the SQL behind the views, this may not be even possible in some cases, e.g. when the view is defined over a pipelined function you'll be hard-pressed to deduce the dependencies on actual tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this product before which was pretty good. You just point it at the database and it will reverse-engineer the schema for you.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio